# Calling winapi function in golang with struct union

Tags: networking, go

I am trying to call the TransmitPackets function on windows using GO.
The goal is to be able to send multiple packets with one syscall (can't be achieved with WSASend [it'll send fragmented IP packets]).

My code panics

```
panic: write udp 192.168.1.26:51817->8.8.8.8:8000: transmitpackets: An invalid argument was supplied.
goroutine 1 [running]:
main.main()
    c:/Users/amit/dev/go/src/rio/main.go:26 +0x210
exit status 2
Process exiting with code: 1
```

Here's my test code

```
package main

import (
    "math/rand"
    "net"
)

func main() {
    raddr, err := net.ResolveUDPAddr("udp", "8.8.8.8:8000")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    con, err := net.DialUDP("udp", nil, raddr)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    packets := make(net.Buffers, 10)
    for i := 0; i < len(packets); i++ {
        packets[i] = make([]byte, 1400)
        rand.Read(packets[i])
    }

    _, err = con.WriteMultiple(packets)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

}
```

and Here's my call to TransmitPackets:

```
type TransmitPacketsElement struct {
    dwElFlags   uint32
    cLength     uint32
    pBuffer     unsafe.Pointer
    nFileOffset uint64
    hFile       uintptr
}

func transmitPackets(s Handle, bufs [][]byte, overlapped *Overlapped) (err error) {
    var maxPacketLen = 0
    tpElements := make([]TransmitPacketsElement, len(bufs))
    for i, tpElement := range tpElements {
        buffer := bufs[i]
        if len(buffer) > maxPacketLen {
            maxPacketLen = len(buffer)
        }
        tpElement.cLength = uint32(len(buffer))
        tpElement.dwElFlags = uint32(uint32(TP_ELEMENT_MEMORY) | uint32(TP_ELEMENT_EOP))
        tpElement.pBuffer = unsafe.Pointer(&buffer[0])
    }
    r1, _, e1 := Syscall6(transmitPacketsFunc.addr, 6, uintptr(s), uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&tpElements[0])), uintptr(uint32(len(tpElements))), uintptr(uint32(maxPacketLen)), uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(overlapped)), 0)
    if r1 == 0 {
        if e1 != 0 {
            err = error(e1)
        } else {
            err = EINVAL
        }
    }
    return
}
```

You can see the full implementation in my modified go 1.8.3 source on [github](https://github.com/amits1995/golang1.8.3-transmitpackets)

Comment: you should copy the entire stack trace and error messages, so people can help you

Comment: How if you remove fields `nFileOffset` and `hFile` from `TransmitPacketsElement` struct? These fields will share their address with `pBuffer`.

Comment: @putu hi thanks for actually taking the time to look at this. I tried removing those fields but still got the same error. any other idea?

Comment: How if you remove only `nFileOffset` not `hFile`? I didn't notice that union inside `TRANSMIT_PACKETS_ELEMENT` takes 16-bytes (I thought it was 8-bytes).

Comment: @putu still no luck :( maybe i'm not passing the array pointer right?

Comment: One more thing, inside the `for` loop, you must use `tpElements[i]` instead of `tpElement`, because `tpElement` is just a copy of an item. So the original element array is left uninitialized. So the loop should be `for i, _ := range tpElements { ... }`

Comment: @putu brilliant! can't believe I missed that. thank you very much it works now!

Comment: You're welcome. Glad it was helpful.